# Promise function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, promise, fetch

Help, I'm just trying to learn the promise function. I am confused how to return the promise function value.

```
static getTrailer(movieId) {
    return fetch(`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=###&append_to_response=videos`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if (responseJson.videos.results[0]) {
                Promise.resolve(responseJson.videos.results[0].key)
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                        return result;
                    });
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(`Trailer is not found`);
            }
        });
}
```

This is where i tried to get the result

```
<p>${DataSource.getTrailer(this._movie.id).then(resultKey => {console.log("data is: " + resultKey)})}</p>
```

But the resultKey always return undefined value. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data down a promise chain, you need to `return` (either explicitly, or implicitly from an arrow function)

Here it is, nice and simple;

```
static getTrailer(movieId) {
    return fetch(`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=###&append_to_response=videos`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => responseJson.videos.results[0].key) // an error thrown for whatever reason, will caught below.
    .catch(error => {
        // an error thrown by any of the three preceding stages will end up here
        throw new Error(`Trailer is not found`); // throwing is less expensive than returning Promise.reject()
    });
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to `.catch()` in the `DataSource.getTrailer()...` expression. Otherwise you'll end up with an "unhandled Promise rejection" error.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i get the key in my custom element ? Here is the example code <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${/*Should be the key*/}">

Comment: A Promise is incapable or returning a result; and your `<p>${......}</p>` expression needs the result. As it stands, it is given a Promise. You'll have to use a completely different technique. Hard to advise without oversight of the general code architecture.

Comment: Best to leave this question as it is, and ask another entitled something like "How to include an asynchronously derived string in another string?". As I understand it, that is effectively what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`if (responseJson.videos.results[0]) {` then you **don't return anything**, so the promise resolves as undefined.

And why are you even doing anything with `Promise.resolve` in the first place?

Get rid of the pointless extra promise, and return the value you want to resolve the `then` with.

```
    .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.videos.results[0]) {
            const result = responseJson.videos.results[0];
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(`Trailer is not found`);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use promise for the get the key again.

```
static getTrailer(movieId) {
    return fetch(`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=###&append_to_response=videos`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if (responseJson.videos.results[0]) {
                result = responseJson.videos.results[0].key;
                console.log(result);
                return result;
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(`Trailer is not found`);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: so, how can i get the key value ?

Comment: see the above code. `key` value is not assigned to result and you can see it in console as well.